# Converting two data frame columns into a factor and associated levels in R

Tags: r, factors, forcats

I have a data frame with two columns of strings that looks like this:

```
phenotype    group
pheno1    group1
pheno1    group1
pheno1    group1
pheno2    group1
pheno2    group1
pheno3    group2
pheno3    group2
pheno4    group2
pheno4    group2
pheno4    group2
```

For plotting purposes I would like to convert the `df$phenotype` column into a factor grouped by the `df$group` column.

So the output would be something like:

```
df$phenotype

[1] pheno1 pheno1 pheno1 pheno2 pheno2 pheno3 pheno3 pheno4 pheno4
Levels: group1 group2
```

Trying to convert with: `factor(df$phenotype, levels = unique(df$group))` obviously returns a lot of NAs.

**EDITED:** Initially I believed the only way I would be able to approach this would be to use `recode()` or forcats after converting the phenotype column to a factor (`factor(df$phenotype)`) followed by something like this:

```
x = factor(df$phenotype)

fct_collapse(x, group1 = c("pheno1", "pheno2"), group2 = c("pheno3", "pheno4"))
```

But I've actually just realised (and so edited this post to reflect the fact) that this actually also does not work because it converts the names of the fields within the factor as well as the level names, which is not what I want.

Comment: I'm trying to parse your sample output, but I don't understand what you want. Did you mean something different there?

Comment: Okay, I tried to edit the sample output to more accurately reflect exactly what I want in this particular instance. I also realised that the forcats thing would not work as I wanted, so I'm now beginning to doubt it's even possible to do what I want with this.

Comment: I think what you want is to have different values and level names, but I don't think that's possible with a factor variable. To accomplish your goal, I think you'd want a 2D data structure like a tibble or data.frame where you can keep the extra data stored in a second variable.